# Finding conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(X\mid (X-0.5)^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have $X$ uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$. How do I find the conditional expectation, $\mathbb{E}(X\mid (X-0.5)^2)$?

My try:
\begin{align}\mathbb{E}((X-0.5)^2\mid (X-0.5)^2)&=(X-0.5)^2\\
\mathbb{E}(X^2-X\mid (X-0.5)^2)&=X^2-X
\end{align}

Beyond this I am totally at a loss. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are given $Y = (X - 0.5)^2$, what possible values can $Y$ take on?
2. Given $Y$, what are the possible values of $X$ that could have resulted in observing $Y$?
3. What is the expected value over all such possible values of $X$ from part (2)?

Part (2) is the critical step.  Here is an example.  If I told you that I observed $Y = (X - 0.5)^2 = 0.1$, then what are the values of $X$ that could have led to me observing $Y = 0.1$?  What then is the expected value of $X$ given $Y$?

Comment: I see $(0,1/4)$ is the interval for $Y$. I need help with the conditional expectation.

Comment: From your answer, I can see, the random variable $E(X\mid (X-0.5)^2)$ takes the constant value 0.5 a.s.. But can you help me with the formal answer?

Comment: You misunderstand. Given a value $Y$ for $(X-0.5)^2$, you can do algebra to find the possible values (plural) that $X$ could have been to start with. For example, when $Y$ is $0.04$, $(X-0.5)$ is $\pm 0.2$.

Comment: And in general X is probability $1/2$ on each of $\{\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{Y} \}$

Comment: So the expectation is $0.5$, right, but there is no random element in this value so "a.s." is not right.

Comment: @JohnFernley Except in countable probability spaces, conditional expectations are **always** defined only "almost surely". Since X is uniform on (0,1), we are in this case.

Comment: @JohnFernley By the way, why did you spoil heropup's educational approach by answering the questions in their post?

Comment: Seeing an answer is more educational, even more so when the hints are not being understood